# Switch user button on KDE Plasma

Tags: fedora, plasma, plasma5

I would like to ask where I can find the switch user button?

I use Fedora 34 (with Plasma) 5.21

Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The switch user functionality has been broken for some time and it was [disabled](https://pagure.io/fedora-kde/kde-settings/c/2d30395742e3e2414d9fa9d944d57049140466b0?branch=f34) in Fedora 34, see [the blocker bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1929643) for details.

You can re-enable it by editing `/usr/share/kde-settings/kde-profile/default/xdg/kdeglobals` and removing/commenting out the `[KDE Action Restrictions]` section.

```
# HOW: https://develop.kde.org/deploy/kiosk/introduction/
# WHY: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1929643
[KDE Action Restrictions]
action/start_new_session=false
action/switch_user=false
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! :)

Comment: Correction: It was broken by Wayland.  If you still use X11 it works just fine.  Yet another feature turned off for everyone just because it's broken in Wayland.  As per the bug thread:

"So, it apears this bug show itself when we use plasma wayland sessions."